# how can i get mount point Use% using shell in OEL

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i wanted to get the Use% of a mount point. I have tried following, but on some hosts i get Use% but on some i am getting Avail

`df -hT /u01/data/backup | awk '{ print $5 }' | egrep -e % | cut -d "%" -f 1`

is there a better way

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3              38G   18G   19G  48% /
tmpfs                  30G     0   30G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             200M  276K  200M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sdc2              22G  6.8G   14G  34% /u01/app/oracle/tools
/dev/mapper/vg_domain-lv_domain
                       50G  1.2G   46G   3% /u01/data/domains
/dev/mapper/vg_middleware-lv_middleware
                       24G  5.6G   17G  26% /u01/app/oracle/middleware
/dev/mapper/vg_jdk-lv_jdk
                      3.9G  402M  3.3G  11% /u01/jdk
/dev/mapper/vg_suite-lv_suite
                       50G   52M   47G   1% /u01/app/oracle/suite
132.240.151.43:/interface
                      600G   55G  546G  10% /interface
```

Comment: On my system (Cygwin), Use% is the 4th column and Avail% is the 5th. You did not provide the `df` output on the systems in question, so I don't know how they look like. Provided that you never see a space in the 'Filesystem' column, the differences could be due to different versions of `df`. You could first parse the title line of the output, to see which columns _Use%_ is. If you are using _Gnu df_, you could use `df -h --output=used` to see **only** this column.

Comment: df output is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` can match, remove the `%` character from the output and limit that output to the value of the `Use%` column.

A general host agnostic version could be:

```
df -hT|awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i~/Use%/){u=i}};NR>1{sub(/%/,"",$u);print $u}'
```

This finds the field that matches `Use%` and captures that field number in `u`. Then, if the record number (`NR`) is greater than one, the percent character in the `u` string is `sub`stituted with an empty string and the value of `u` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a real line-break after i.e. */dev/mapper/vg_domain-lv_domain* and you have installed (or can install) GNU df, I suggest that you retrieve the value by i.e.

```
 df -h --output=pcent,source
```

instead.